# How to monitoring WSO2 ESB is alive with JMX?

Tags: wso2, monitoring, jmx, jconsole, wso2-esb

I want to monitoring an WSO2 ESB instance with JMX in remote using JConsole, but I don't find any method in https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/JMX+Monitoring to check if WSO2 ESB is alive or not.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at org.wso2.carbon:type=ServerAdmin, you will fin an attribute named "ServerStatus" with a value "RUNNING"

Comment: Yes, There is an attribute named "alive" with a value "RUNNING". Thanks ;)

Comment: The attribute "alive" as a value "true" ;-)

Comment: Yes, sorry. ServerStatus as a value "RUNNING".

When this attribute has false value? If Carbon is down, JMX not working. Does Its value is always true?

Comment: If Carbon is down, you can't connect to the JVM with JMX so, you will not find other values...